# TFS: Delete and re-create Files, TFS doesn't see the Add

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, tfs

When I delete and re-add a file in Visual Studio, which is under TFS-SourceControl, if I check in, the TFS only detects the Delete, but not the add.
Since we trigger a "Compile"-Check after each checkin, this always triggers an error, since the newly added File is not found, so we have to check-in twice.

Is there a possibility to tell the TFS to mark the deleted/added file not as deleted, but just as changed?

Comment: Are you sure if you save solution file after adding it again? Please do save all and then check check it in.

Comment: Under excluded changes (in pending changes) there is an "Detected" link. Did you check there already? I've expreienced that sometimes changes are not recognized as changes but only as POSSIBLE changes and thus land there instead of on the included changes list

Comment: @ Prasanth: Tried it, still not detect. I guess there is no change on the project file anyway, since I re-generate the file with the same name.
@Thomas: You are right, they are excluded, but I can't add them since they say I have to check-in the delete first

Comment: Is there a reason why you're trying to do this via Delete/Add rather than just checking out the files and over-writing them? TFS will want to see the old/new files as two distinct entities with separate histories.

Comment: "This always triggers an error", *always*? Why are you doing this *all the time*? I think I have come across this scenario, delete and re-add a new file in its place, once or twice in my entire career, what is your workflow that demands that you do something this way? As others have commented here, the workflow should be that you just check out the file for editing to begin with, then change it, then check it back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do? If you delete the file, TFS will set the state of the file in source control to "delete pending". It isn't possible to then change the state of the file again to something else without either first checking in the pending change or undoing it. Delete and Add are incompatible pending changes on the same object.

Surely if you are deleting then re-adding a file you are in effect making an edit change, which would be properly tracked in the history. Why not check the file out for edit and assuming the new content is radically different from the original, overwrite the checked out file with the new content and then check it back in.

Comment: We re-created the file automatically. In order to keep this creation-code in, we checked if the file exists or not. But I changed it, so you have to uncomment the creation-code and the file gets updated every time.

Comment: You really should not store generated code under source controll

Answer (score 1):

select the files that don't have the **blue lock icon** next to them and open the context menu and add them to **source control** (`include in project`) then Pending changes will see them

Comment: Tried this one, the problem is, this option isnt avaliable, because the TFS thinks the file is already there, so I can only select "Check in" etc.

Comment: @MatthiasMüller so the files have the blue lock (are in source control ) ??

Comment: @MatthiasMüller did you already check if TFS just sees the add as "only" a possible add instead of a real add?

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was with re-added Table in **`Entity-Framework`**.

In EF DB-First **when changing column definition in DB, EF does not detect any change or when removing a column**. (ex: when making a column nullable)

This is only fixed by removing and re-adding the table in the `edmx`.

`TFS` only detects the remove, not the add of the table's `.cs` file. Then TFS doesnt let you revert the delete because "`file already exists`"

This can be fixed by opening the local CS file in a text editor to save the current generated code (1. save the local cs class), then delete the file (to match the tfs state) so that you can revert the delete in the pending changes (2. delete the physical cs file) (3. revert delete in the pending changes window), then manually replace the reverted cs file code with the one saved in the text editor (4. manually update the cs class with the code saved in '1'). Review and Commit your changes.